# pandas.date_range with np.datetime returns error

Tags: pandas, parameters, date-range

```
min_date = data['mie_time'][data['mie_time'] != np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00')].min() #numpy.datetime64('2019-01-01T05:44:05')

max_date = data['mie_time'].max() #numpy.datetime64('2019-01-01T07:14:35')

data['mie_datetime'] = pd.date_range(start=min_date, end=max_date, periods=len(data['mie_time'])).to_pydatetime().view(np.ma.MaskedArray)
```

When I try this code I get the error massage

ValueError: Of the three parameters: start, end, and periods, exactly two must be specified

Does someone have an idea whats the problem?

Comment: Yes, I know - `Of the three parameters: start, end, and periods, exactly two must be specified`

Comment: So try remove `end` or `periods` parameter

Comment: Note that `pandas` changed the API recently. In the most recent version (0.25.1), you may specify the three parameters at the same time. Maybe upgrading `pandas` could be an option, if @jezrael's suggestion is not an option for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states :

[0.25.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)  -- date_range

```
>>> pd.date_range(start='2018-04-24', end='2018-04-27', periods=3)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-04-24 00:00:00', '2018-04-25 12:00:00',
               '2018-04-27 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

[0.22.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.date_range.html)  -- data_range

The documentation clearly states this : 
`Of the three parameters: start, end, and periods, exactly two must be specified.`

So for you to use the `periods`, upgrading to `0.25.1` would be the option.